# R: Piping with dplyr returns additional NULL

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to get the mean squared error from a model in a dplyr pipeline.
Somehow when I use dplyr the output is NULL instead of the desired error measure.

Why is that?

MWE:

```
require(dplyr)
data("iris")
iris %>% 
 CVlm(form.lm = formula(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width), m = 2) %>% 
 attributes(.)["ms"] #Returns NULL instead of 0.719

cvlm_model <- CVlm(data = iris, form.lm = formula(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width), m = 2)
attributes(cvlm_model)['ms'] # Returns 0.719
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use curly braces

```
library(magrittr)
library(DAAG)

iris %>% 
 CVlm(form.lm = formula(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width), m = 2) %>%
 {attributes(.)["ms"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you're after

```
iris %>% 
  CVlm(form.lm = formula(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width), m = 2) %>% 
  attributes %>% .$ms

# [1] 0.719
```